# How can we interpret a covariance of a data wth zero mean?

Tags: covariance

Covariance Matrix of Zero Mean Data. The data set has zero mean does it somehow relects in covariance matrix ?

Comment: You can shift the means without affecting the covariance matrix, so in that sense there is little relationship

Comment: Thanks Henry. What I exactly would like to know between a zero mean data set and a non zero mean data set if we can interpret the data set by seeing the covariance matrix ?

Comment: If all you can see is the covariance matrix, then you have no information about the means (except that they are finite)

Comment: Thanks Henry.  Further, is there any method/way to check the zero mean data set when the actual data set is not available ?